# How to run ajax to fill data in a template from controller in angularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

I am working on an angularJS project. I have written ajax that gets data continuously from my RESTful service. My ajax code is in my controller. Now I want to use the received data and display it in my template. I have placed a

tag in my template whose id is "demo" and in my ajax in controller, I am using `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Paragraph changed!";`

to fill in the new data every 3 seconds. For some reason, the data is not being updated in my template even though console log is display the data.

NOTE: This is a rough code where I don't care about security/performance/practice at the moment.

Does anyone see why?

My controller:

```
.controller('geolocationCtrl', function($scope, $state, $stateParams, $ionicPopup, $timeout) {

  //popup alert starts here
   $scope.showAlert = function(status,message) {
   var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
     title: status,
     template: message,
   });
 };
 //popup alert ends here


  setInterval(function update_map(){

        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "http://example.com/provider/rest.php/geolocation",
            type: "GET",

            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function(resultData) {

                            console.log(resultData.latitude);
                            console.log(resultData.longitude);
                            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = resultData.latitude;

            },
            error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            },

        });

    }, 3000);


  $scope.state = $state.current
  $scope.params = $stateParams;

})
```

My template:

```
<p id="demo">

        </p>
```

Comment: You're missing the concept of angularJS here.. AngularJS is capable of two-way data binding. So, you just need to setup the model in your controller and bind it in your view. And everytime you do AJAX calls, and you update your model in controller, your view will also be updated.

Comment: @choz is right: use angular `$http` to get data from server, not `jQuery.ajax`...

Comment: Can you please write me some demo code here? I can't seem to get my head around it

Comment: @Daniel Just a suggestion, you might want to start the basics at [Codecademy](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-angularjs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use jquery when using Angular. Use $http as such, which will allow you to change the data in your scope variables hence changing the view in the template dynamically.

So instead of

```
     jQuery.ajax({
        url: "http://example.com/provider/rest.php/geolocation",
        type: "GET",

        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function(resultData) {

                        console.log(resultData.latitude);
                        console.log(resultData.longitude);
                        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = resultData.latitude;

        },
        error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        },

    });
```

Do this

```
    $http({
        url: "http://example.com/provider/rest.php/geolocation",
        method: "get",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        }).success:(function(resultData) {
           $scope.something = resultData
        }).error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        });
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense. But how do i actually display the data in the template. Do I use {{params.something}} or how?

Comment: you can do a ng-bind='someVariableName.someParamName'

Comment: so for example <div ng-bind='person.name'></div> where there should be a $scope.person object in your controller.

Comment: You can also do a {{person.Name}} but it is not recommended. This is because sometimes on page load you may see the code {{person.Name}} before angular evaluates it.

Comment: you seem to know a lot about this stuff, can you look at my question here please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36862704/how-to-convert-a-google-maps-html-js-designed-interface-into-angularjs-interface