# How to convert a google maps html/js designed interface into angularJS interface

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

I am creating an application where I have created a google maps interface for desktop where I show the markers on the desktop. I can drag the markers on the screen and data such as coordinates and distance gets filled in my input fields. Now I am making the same version of my app in angularJS. I have implemented angularjs-google-maps directive. But I am having trouble with converting the functions into angularJS that I had designed in desktop. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Here is my code in html/js:

```
                    <div id="map" style="width: 400px; height: 300px;" >
  <input id="duration" type="hidden" name="duration"></input>
  <input id="distance" type="hidden" name="distance"></input>
 <input id="origin_longitude" type="hidden" name="origin_longitude"></input>
 <input id="origin_latitude" type="hidden" name="origin_latitude"></input>
 <input id="destination_longitude" type="hidden" name="destination_longitude"></input>
<input id="destination_latitude" type="hidden" name="destination_longitude"></input>


<script type="text/javascript">

function initialize() {
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    draggable: true
  });

  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 7,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    streetViewControl: false,
  }

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

   function address_to_coordinates_lat(address_text, callback) {
    var address = address_text;
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        callback(results[0].geometry.location.lat());
      } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      }
    });
  }
  function address_to_coordinates_long(address_text, callback) {
    var address = address_text;
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        callback(results[0].geometry.location.lng());
      } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      }
    });
  }



var request = {
    origin: 'Chicago', 
    destination: 'New York',
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
  };



  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      google.maps.event.addListener(directionsDisplay, 'directions_changed', function() {
        directions = directionsDisplay.getDirections();

        console.log(directions.routes[0].legs[0].start_address);
        console.log(directions.routes[0].legs[0].end_address);


        // Display the distance:
        document.getElementById('distance').value =
          directions.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value;
        // Display the duration:
        document.getElementById('duration').value =
          directions.routes[0].legs[0].duration.value;
         //Display origin latitude
        address_to_coordinates_lat(directions.routes[0].legs[0].start_address, function(location){
            document.getElementById('origin_latitude').value =
          location;
                });     
        //Display origin longitude
        address_to_coordinates_long(directions.routes[0].legs[0].start_address, function(location){
            document.getElementById('origin_longitude').value =
          location;
                });

         //Display destination latitude
        address_to_coordinates_lat(directions.routes[0].legs[0].end_address, function(location){
            document.getElementById('destination_latitude').value =
          location;
                });     
        //Display destination longitude
        address_to_coordinates_long(directions.routes[0].legs[0].end_address, function(location){
            document.getElementById('destination_longitude').value =
          location;
                });

      })
    } else {
      alert("directions request failed:" + status)
    }
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);

   </script>
```

Now I want to use exactly the same system in angularJS but simply copy/pasting doesnt work. So i have to convert the functions for angularJS or something?

Comment: Have you tried `ng-map`?? https://ngmap.github.io/

Comment: thats what I am using but the problem is how do i convert this function into an ngmap function? :(

Comment: Sorry mate :) I have never delved so deep into Angular. Never worked on this API as well. Hope you find your answer here.